# XMR-stack optimization. beginner troubles

Tags: mining-pools, cpu-mining, hashrate

I am currently using the latest version of XMR-stak that self-sets-up, but I am only seeing a hash-rate of around 100 H/s.

**Here are my system specs:**

laptop: Lenovo Y50 touch

processor: Intel Core i7-4720HQ CPU

RAM: 8GB

graphics: Intel HD graphics 4600

**And here is my mining configuration:**

"cpu_threads_conf" :

[

```
{ "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "affine_to_cpu" : 0 },


{ "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "affine_to_cpu" : 2 },


{ "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "affine_to_cpu" : 4 },
```

],

I am basically wondering if there is anything I can do to get above 100 H/s or is that the best a laptop can get without booting Linux.

***Thanks in advance!***

EDIT: formatting

Answer (score 1):

Thats about right per: http://monerobenchmarks.info/searchCPU.php

```
CPU MODEL              HASHRATE         APP         PARAM       OS          TDP         Date
INTEL CORE I7 4720HQ    110 H/s      MINERGATE 7.2  N/A     WINDOWS 10 x64  43 W    Jan, 2018.
```

Comment: Agreed but I'll just add - you may want to ensure huge pages is correctly configured.